# Unity Shortcuts in Linux Mint

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint

Does anybody know how to put usefull unity keyboard shortcuts on Linux Mint Cinnamon? 
Like to maximize current window to the left side, or to change to the right workspace with ctrl+alt+right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Menu > Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts`

'Maximize current window to the left' is called 'Push tile left' and is under `Windows > Tiling and Snapping`

You can set keyboard shortcuts for switching workspaces in the 'Workspaces' category.

However, Linux Mint Cinnamon already has these keyboard shortcuts by default.

Push tile left = Super+Left

Swith to right workspace = Ctrl+Alt+ight